# How to disable kotlinx serialization polymorphic descriminator?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I'm generating JSON for a number of third-party APIs. Many of them accept a list (JSON array) of different objects, however, none of them will accept the `"type": "com.mycom.someclass"` automatically generated by kotlinx serialization due to the polymorphic nature of the list.

In my use-case, I only care about serializing out. No deserialization is needed.

Current:

```
[{"type":"com.mycom.Child1","x":"child1"}, {"type":"com.mycom.Child2","y": 23}]
```

Needed:

```
[{"x":"child1"}, {"y": 23}]
```

How can I disable this automatic behavior?

Comment: There's no easy way to do it. See [this issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/464)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Json parametric polymorphic deserialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json_transformations.md#json-parametric-polymorphic-deserialization):

> You also can serialize data with such serializer. In that case, either registered or default serializer would be selected for the actual property type in runtime. **No class discriminator would be added.**

You'll need to impelement `JsonParametricSerializer` and manually select the serializer. As you don't need to support deserialization, the implementation would be trivial.

Comment: I take it this approach does not work for nested sealed hierarchies. That is, the JsonParametricSerializer can only be used at the top level of a class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to make the polymorphic type distinctive. As an example

```
sealed class Vehicle {
   data class Car(...)
   data class Bike(...)
}

val v: Vehicle = Vehicle.Car()

// Contains "type" as you serialize Vehicle, which is polymorphic
val json1 = Json.encodeToString(v) 

// Does not contain "type" as you serialize Vehicle.Car, which is distinctive
val json2 = when(v) {
    is Vehicle.Car -> Json.encodeToString(v)
    is Vehicle.Bike -> Json.encodeToString(v)
}
```

Same when you'd use this in Ktor:

```
// Contains "type" as you serialize Vehicle, which is polymorphic
setBody(v) 

// Does not contain "type" as you serialize Vehicle.Car, which is distinctive
val json2 = when(v) {
    is Vehicle.Car -> setBody(v)
    is Vehicle.Bike -> setBody(v)
}
```